# Propagation delay in full adder models

Tags: delay, adder, propagation

From my last question [Propgation delay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432336/propgation-delay?noredirect=1#comment1079531_432336)
[image]

I tried to solve for the time delay that occurs at the last carry 
[image]

Not sure if I have done it right .. Please correct me if I m wrong

Comment: I don't like the idea of checking your homework for you. If you have a question about how to do it, then ask your question.

Comment: Oka did i usevthe right way?